# SQL add unique 3 columns where 4 is NULL

Tags: sql, unique

I have 3 columns: `Number`, `StepNumber`, `LineId`.

I want to make them unique but only where fourth column `FinishTime` is `NULL`.

If `FinishTime` is not `NULL` those three columns cannot be unique.

I have tried:

```
ALTER TABLE myTable ADD CONSTRAINT checkUnique UNIQUE (Number, StepNumber, LineId)
```

but it's forbidden to add `WHERE FinishTime IS NULL`.

[image: Example]

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Answer (score 0):

Include column FinishTime also in the constraint definition.

```
ALTER TABLE myTable ADD CONSTRAINT checkUnique UNIQUE (Number, StepNumber, LineId, FinishTime)
```

Answer (score 0):

Create unique nonclustered index

```
Create unique nonclustered index [my_index]
on [mytable]([FinishTime])
where [FinishTime] is not null
```